# Implementing "Read More" in .NET with MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm writing a simple "blog" application in .NET with MVC3, as a learning exercise.

To implement - rudimentary - "read more" functionality, I've added a custom button to tiny_mce which, when pressed, inserts

```
<!--#readmore#-->
```

into the post content.

The idea is to obtain the content up to that point to show on the homepage and then add a link if there's more to read, as done by every blog engine ever.

Doing this is pretty straightforward, the question I have is *where* should I do it? Right now, I have the functionality in the Post model:

```
public String content_read_more()
    {
        if (this.content.Contains("<!--#readmore#-->"))
        {
            int position = this.content.IndexOf("<!--#readmore#-->");
             this.has_read_more = true; 
            return this.content.Substring(0, position);
        }
        else
        {
            this.has_read_more = false;
            return this.content;                 
        }
    }
```

I avoided creating the link to the complete post within the model, since it didn't seem to be something the Model should do.

But, doing it like that, I have to check if the post has more content in the view:

```
<div class="content">
    @Html.Raw(item.content_read_more())
    @if (item.hasReadMoreLink())
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Leer más", "Details", new { id = item.id })
    }
</div>
```

which introduces logic into the view.

Should I do it in the controller? Is there a better way to do this? Am I thinking about this way too hard?

Thank you!

Comment: .Net public member names should be UpperCamelCase.

Comment: @SLaks, that's a convention, and a good idea, but saying it "should" be like implies anything else is wrong; I don't think that's accurate

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs, you mean to call the rest of the content?

Comment: @mno4k, please disregard, it was off topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's perfectly normal.
There is nothing wrong with adding simple `if`s in the view.

You should avoid adding *business logic* in the view; instead, you should put it in the control and send the results to the view (exactly as you're doing now).

Comment: So, thinking about it way too hard, then? Thank you for the answer :).